# Decoding call inputs

Tags: solidity, bytes

Using a smart contract's ABI and the input data from a transaction on Etherscan, I am able to decode the input data using this tool: https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/

**Output**

```
{
  "method": "execute",
  "types": [
    "address",
    "bytes"
  ],
  "inputs": [
    "c5cc1dfb64a62b9c7bb6cbf53c2a579e2856bf92",
    {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
        159,
        108,
        61,
        189,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        90,
        167,
        26,
        58,
        225,
        192,
        189,
        106,
        194,
        122,
        31,
        40,
        225,
        65,
        95,
        255,
        182,
        241,
        91,
        140,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        234,
        25,
        13,
        189,
        199,
        173,
        242,
        101,
        38,
        14,
        196,
        218,
        110,
        150,
        117,
        253,
        79,
        90,
        120,
        187,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        13,
        224,
        182,
        179,
        167,
        100,
        0,
        0
      ]
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    "_target",
    "_data"
  ]
}
```

`method`, `types` and `inputs[0]` are all self explanatory, however I am looking to decode the `bytes` object in `inputs[1]`.

All I know is that it led to the following "internal transactions". How can I actually read the methods that were called on the address `c5cc1dfb64a62b9c7bb6cbf53c2a579e2856bf92`? https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xffc071b71dc25813df4b6dd4b412940a3ab7f426664cf7f51e49dae57de7853e#internal

ABI and input data below for anyone who may want to recreate using the tool above:

**ABI**

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"owner_","type":"address"}],"name":"setOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_target","type":"address"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"response","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_code","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"target","type":"address"},{"name":"response","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"cache","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"authority_","type":"address"}],"name":"setAuthority","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_cacheAddr","type":"address"}],"name":"setCache","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"authority","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_cacheAddr","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":true,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"sig","type":"bytes4"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"foo","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"name":"bar","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"fax","type":"bytes"}],"name":"LogNote","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"authority","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetAuthority","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetOwner","type":"event"}]
```

**Input Data**

```
0x1cff79cd000000000000000000000000c5cc1dfb64a62b9c7bb6cbf53c2a579e2856bf92000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000649f6c3dbd0000000000000000000000005aa71a3ae1c0bd6ac27a1f28e1415fffb6f15b8c000000000000000000000000ea190dbdc7adf265260ec4da6e9675fd4f5a78bb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Ethereum ABI decoder the transaction is calling the function `execute(address _target, bytes _data)` we have that it is being called with this parameters (after transforming them to hex):

- `_target` = 0xc5cc1dfb64a62b9c7bb6cbf53c2a579e2856bf92
- `_data` = 0x9f6c3dbd00000....0de0b6b3a7640000 (length 100 bytes or 200 hex chars)

Examining the source code at `https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9568eef80fdb55f68fbfe2e2d59f1b698e2819bd#code` it delegatecall to the `_target` and pass `_data` as input for that contract.

We can use Ethereum ABI decoder again with the `_data` obtained previously and the ABI from Etherscan at `0xc5cc1dfb64a62b9c7bb6cbf53c2a579e2856bf92`. We get the following

```
{
  "method": "join",
  "types": [
    "address",
    "address",
    "uint256"
  ],
  "inputs": [
    "5aa71a3ae1c0bd6ac27a1f28e1415fffb6f15b8c",
    "ea190dbdc7adf265260ec4da6e9675fd4f5a78bb",
    "de0b6b3a7640000"
  ],
  "names": [
    "daiJoin",
    "pot",
    "wad"
  ]
}
```

It is calling `join(address daiJoin, address pot, uint256 wad)` with

- daiJoin = 0x5aa71a3ae1c0bd6ac27a1f28e1415fffb6f15b8c
- pot = 0xea190dbdc7adf265260ec4da6e9675fd4f5a78bb
- wad = 0xde0b6b3a7640000